# How to interpret feature weights from Google autoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl

I've created a number of models using Google AutoML and I want to make sure I'm interpreting the output data correctly. This if for a linear regression model predicting website conversion rates on any given day.

First the model gives a model feature importance when the model has completed training. This seems to tell me which feature was most important in predicting the target value but not necessarily if it contributes most to larger changes in that value?

Secondly, we have a bunch of local feature weights which I think tell me the contribution each feature has made to prediction. So say feature weight of bounce rate has a weight of -0.002 we can say that the bounce rate for that row decreased the prediction by 0.002? Is there a correct way to aggregate that, is it just the range?

Comment: Feature importance will tell you the overall contribution of the feature to model predictions. When interpreting linear model coefficients you have the weight that is multiplied by the feature value. If all features have the same scale then you can compare the values of the weights. You can also use the SHAP package for understanding single sample predictions https://github.com/slundberg/shap one more option is to use MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised it has decision tree visualization + rule extraction, feature importance visualization, and SHAP plots.

Comment: Wow, thats a lot to get stuck into! Am I able to just take my model made in Google autoML and start using it with these packages, do you know?

Comment: @pplonski the more i look at it, can i simply plot my local feature weights against my feature values to observe how each feature impacts the prediction? Can I also just take summary data from each set of local feature weights e.g. min, max, lower quartlie, median, upper quartile to see the range of contributions? Or does that not make sense?

Comment: I assume that your are using AutoML Tables (correct me if I am wrong), which computes feature importance using the [Sampled Shapley method](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/ai-explanations/overview#compare-methods)

Comment: Regarding your first question, as for regression models, the local feature importance for a prediction tells you how much each feature added to or subtracted from the result as compared with the baseline prediction score ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/explain#local)),
I believe that the most important a feature is to predict a target value, the most it must contribute to larger changes in that value.

Comment: About the second part of your question. When you say `local feature weights', you are also referring to [local feature importance](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/explain#local) right?

Comment: @AaronHarris yes, it makes sense. Remember to check the scale in features.

Comment: @pplonski thank you! how do you mean check the scale?

Comment: @Ksign correct, using AutoML Tables from Google. I am getting the local feature importance yes, and getting them when generating predictions and sending those to BigQuery. Seems that I can simply plot the feature values vs the local feature weights to get a view of how each feature is impacting the prediction.

Comment: check the min, max range

Comment: I believe that you will find [Feature Attributions](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/ai-explanations/overview#feature_attributions) useful then. The attribution scores show how much the feature affected the change in prediction value, relative to the baseline value that you specify